# 17 years old - made a mistake and got fired for stealing $50 at my first job - what other job options could I have?

Tags: job-search, termination, retail, food-industry

I used to work at a fast food store and I made a really stupid mistake by stealing $50 and had to suffer the consequences of being fired. Now I'm worried if i can't or won't be able to get hired anywhere else. I had good things ahead of me - I'm in a welding tech program getting certified to weld and my grades are always low 90s. Does anyone know what jobs might take me as a 17 year old with my problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101634/discussion-on-question-by-iamalex00057988-17-years-old-made-a-mistake-and-got).

Answer (score 100):

Unless the issue is being followed up on by the police, the matter is closed. Fast food is entry level work and presumably you are seeking to obtain similar work, so just leave the job off your resume and apply to other places.

You may want to change your username for this question, as I Googled the name you have and can match certain identifying information to details.

Use this as a guide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85818/how-can-i-change-my-name-on-a-stack-exchange-site

Deleting the question is not enough as others on this site can still view a deleted question.

Some future employer finding this could be extremely consequential for your future.

Comment: deleting the question would already limit its visibility down to <1% of internet users. I came here because of hot questions, so it's only getting worse.

Comment: Maybe it's a smear!

Comment: @GuntherStruyf yeah, the calculus changes as this explodes in popularity immediately (rather than being a waiting time bomb).

Answer (score 27):

I'm assuming you were just caught and fired on the spot. If so, that is likely the end of it.

Unless you were arrested, indicted, found guilty, or have a warrant out for your arrest, you should be OK. Otherwise, if it was a juvenile conviction, your "record" goes away when you reach a certain age (or so I'm told - this may vary depending on which state you are in).

But you may want to leave the grocery store off your resume.

Answer (score 11):

There are good advices in [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/148863/112259), just adding a specific point:

From my own small experience in a big well known fast-food brand when I was student (starts with "Mc", actually in France but I assume it's the same in other countries), they keep internal records of past employees and share them at least nation-wide. So if it's a big fast-food brand you may not be able to work in another restaurant in the same brand. In another brand it should be OK.

To be more precise, in my case it was very benign: I had resigned from a position in one restaurant without being very arranging in the time between prior notice and effective departure. When applying in another restaurant later, I was told by the interviewer I was "kind of blacklisted" for that (actually still managed to get the position because it was benign and I showed motivation).

Comment: That sort of information retention may well be contrary to GDPR within the EU. It depends on the time between the 'resigning' and the 'applying' and if GDPR regulation was in force at the time. 'Mc' may have made themselves liable for a potentially massive fine

Comment: @houninym thanks for the precision, it was way before GDPR. It's worth noting that in France, "Mc" restaurants are franchises that are associated to a national institution, they are not strictly speaking the same company even if bound to a lot of rules from the franchise. Don't know if the same in other countries

Comment: @Kaddath very much the same on this side of the pond. There may be individuals/corporations who own a dozen or more "Mc"s or "King"s, but they only follow the rules of the franchiser, they're not owned by nor do they have full data sharing with said franchiser

Comment: @houninym Maybe, but then again you might be forced to approve the usage of this data when you start working there. GDPR doesn't mean companies are not allowed to own data about you. Some type of records (normally accounting) are mandatory to keep by law and GDPR won't protect that.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a criminal record for that? Do you want to work in the same industry?

If both the answers are negative you are most likely okay and may live happily ever after. Even if you had the record there is still a chance the employer-to-be won't be that much concerned about it. The longer record of jobs without issues, the better.

You did a really stupid thing. Shit happens. Everybody makes mistakes, some more serious some lesser serious. If you have learnt the lesson, good for you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's a great sign that you recognize that stealing your company was a terrible decision. Some people never acknowledge their mistakes and end traping themselves in a endless circle of self justifications.

Second, we all make mistakes. Some even break the law and, as you experienced, all, in a way or another, suffer the consequences of their actions. You did break the law, but don't let this one mistake define you or let people define you by this one mistake.

Now care to never put yourself in a situation like this again. Do walk under the law of your country and walk under wherever company policies you work in the future.

About new job opportunities, you will find a new job, just take this experience out of your professional life and you are good to go.

You are young and there is a vast way ahead of you. Lots of mistakes to do and lots of opportunities to amend thoses mistakes. Amend this one, raise your head and move on.

Answer (score -5):

having criminal record , you have more than 1 job that will not affected with your reputation like working online .. etc  , and I think that u are a good man because u admits that u are  guilty , you can make a a lot of good things to the community  for the coming years .

Comment: This doesn't answer the original poster's question.

Answer (score -11):

Considering that you are just 17 years old and you have stolen just $50, I would simply tell the truth during the job interview (if they ask you about reason of ending your last job). Honestly.. stealing money is pretty common, and can even happen by mistake.

I do not agree with others that you should be deleting the question or changing your name. You haven't done anything terrible. You just stole $50, that's it, omg :D  It is not the end of the world, and you asking about it under your real name only shows your honesty and real concern about what you have done.

So don't worry, good people will understand and will give you the chance you deserve!

Comment: Do not admit to stealing money in ANY job interview, unless directly asked the question "have you ever stolen any money?" and there is proof that you have, and your potential employer will check.

Comment: @numenor If you want to be pretending you are perfect your whole life, then go with it. :-)  If you want to work at company which will treat you as human being, then be honest with them from the very beginning. It is worth it, trust me.

Comment: maybe you're right. However, using whether or not an employer cares that you stole stuff in the past as a kind of filter for whether you want to work for them is just silly. You can usually decide that from other information

Comment: @numenor That is true. But I think it is also silly to not hire 17 years old becase they stole $50 in last job.

Comment: I agree with you. But many people do not, and they may be the ones hiring him

Comment: I'd like a citation for "stealing money is pretty common". I have never done so, and it's not my impression that my peers have either.

Comment: If you have multiple candidates, which would you choose from a *business* perspective?

Comment: @Michael Durrant The one who I can trust.

Comment: I would be somewhat disinclined to hire someone who had stolen without evidence of a true change of heart—not just an increased determination to avoid negative consequences, but truly a change in *character*. This does not make me any less than a good person, as your last sentence implies. On the contrary, since I have a very serious responsibility to my employer to hire the best candidate for the job and to pass over candidates who exhibit *anything* that could predict future problems, I would be *less than* "a good person" to simply ignore a candidate's past errors without a good reason.

Comment: @CodeSeeker You cannot predict what will people do. By your strategy, you are more likely to accept people who have not yet done something bad, or who are dishonest, or who don't realize that have done something bad. This is just flawed logic. It is not how you will find a good person. That is like saying that someone who once crashed into wall with a car is more likely to do so again. It just doesn't make any sense. I believe that it is simply impossible to analyze someone during few minutes or hours. No psychology expert can do that. It is just guessing.

Comment: @Firzen The issue in this chat to be you are analyzing the question from your subjective standpoint of, paraphrasing here and correct me if I'm wrong, "It is bad/dumb/silly not to hire someone like OP because of what OP did."  I don't think anybody would really disagree with that general premise. However, if the purpose here is to leave OP with good advice based on his question, your answer and comments are not likely to achieve that end. And the strawmans you're throwing up don't help, either (for example, your reply to numenor - nothing he said had anything to do with claiming perfection)

Comment: @Firzen that’s right—interview are very poorly correlated to candidate outcomes. However, they are the only tool most companies will even consider using. Furthermore, none of that means they have no value or predictive power whatsoever. If you find a negative in an interview, it’s treasonable and logical to take it under consideration.

Comment: @Firzen "That is like saying that someone who once crashed into wall with a car is more likely to do so again" - this is a pretty common belief in the car insurance industry.